# Как из папки с проектом выделить файлы проекта?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Есть проект. В нем присутствует много чего лишнего, кроме файлов с настройками проекта и файлов исходного кода. Мне же надо выделить из него только то, что нужно для работы над ним на другом компьютере. Я бы, конечно, быстренько сварганил утилитку, которая бы достала файлы с нужным расширением, но в проект могут быть включены различные данные (html, xml, xsd и тд).

Comment: По каким признакам вы разделяете файлы на нужные/ненужные?

Comment: @free_ze, если бы я смог это сформулировать, я бы уже написал программу, которая бы делала то что мне нужно. Я не знаю всех признаков. Признак один, этих файлов должно быть достаточно, чтобы я мог скомпилировать проект на другом компе (естественно, предполагается, что на другом компе установлена нужная версия .net framework).

Comment: Пока ваш вопрос звучит, как: "Сходи не знаю куда, достань то, не знаю что!". Все необходимые для сборки файлы перечислены в файле проекта (для С# это .csproj, ноды "Compile", "Reference" и подобное) и/или в инструкциях MSBuild'а. Но вопрос в том, что вообще делают лишние файлы в директориях проекта?

Comment: @free_ze, что делают? они там лежат. Нормально звучит задача, если вы, конечно, хоть раз открывали папку с проектом. Там как минимум лежат PDB файлы и бинарники. Их надо исключить, но при этом не исключать бинарники библиотек, которые получены с NuGet... нюансов еще больше. О каких то я могу даже не подозревать.

Comment: Можно сделать [cleanup проекта](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/20f0363c-ea7c-47a3-9dcb-3d8d2f74b463/how-to-clean-solution-from-command-line?forum=msbuild). Nuget-сборки тоже не нужны, т.к. они референсы на них регистрируются и недостающие подтягиваются из интернетов автоматически при каждой сборке проекта. Все, конечно же, зависит от сложности и состава вашего проекта. Проектный файл и инструкции MSBuild представляют собой XML-формат, который описывает этапы сборки, отладки и деплоя. Если внимательно его почитать, то найдутся ответы на все вопросы.

Comment: И, да, папки bin, obj, packages можно просто сносить целиком. После сборки они появятся снова.

Comment: Еще хинт: можно посмотреть какие-нибудь opensource-проекты и что люди исключают через файл gitignore. Так как репозиторий рассчитывается на то, что человек его разворачивает с нуля, то там оказывается все необходимое и достаточное для этого.

Comment: @free_ze, на десяток проектов уже несподручно удалять везде bin и obj. А за идею с гит-игнором спасибо.

Comment: Вы ж не руками клонируете проект, так в чем проблема написать простой скрипт? Структура проектов типовая.

Comment: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Comment: @VladD, а чем парсить данный файл? Ну, может есть готовое решение, надоело клепать велосипеды

Comment: @iRumba: Ну так один раз вручную набейте список, делов-то. Парсеров gitignore на C# [вроде нет](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32506510/276994), так что если вы напишете и положите на гитхаб, будет первый.

Comment: @VladD, для того ,чтобы написать годный парсер, нужна схема документа. Не знаете где достать схему gitignore?

Comment: @iRumba: Ну, вот [тут](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) есть раздел Pattern Format, который по идее описывает то, что нужно.